# MissingRegionError with aws sdk and paperclip Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am building a website application with rails version 4.2.4 ,paperclip and aws sdk version 2.I am getting an error 
**Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError - missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']:**
while uploading my user avatar.

While in my console the result of Aws.config[:region] is "ap-southeast-1"

My configuration for aws-sdk in  initializers/aws.rb

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})
```

My configuration for paperclip in enviroment/development.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'],
  :region => ENV['AWS_REGION'],
  :s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
  }
}
```

My user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 # devise :database_authenticatable, 
      #   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable


devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,:registerable#,:validatable
acts_as_paranoid


  validates_attachment :avatar,content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
            size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }

end
```

Error log

```
Aws::Errors::MissingRegionError - missing region; use :region option or export region name to ENV['AWS_REGION']:
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.20) lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/regional_endpoint.rb:30:in `after_initialize'
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.20) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:84:in `block in after_initialize'
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.20) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:83:in `after_initialize'
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.20) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:21:in `initialize'
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.20) lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:105:in `new'
  aws-sdk-resources (2.1.20) lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:169:in `extract_client'
  aws-sdk-resources (2.1.20) lib/aws-sdk-resources/resource.rb:15:in `initialize'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:278:in `obtain_s3_instance_for'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:269:in `s3_interface'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:286:in `s3_bucket'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:298:in `s3_object'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:410:in `block in flush_writes'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/storage/s3.rb:378:in `flush_writes'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:239:in `save'
   () home/akhil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/paperclip-110900276c99/lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:92:in `block in add_active_record_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:228:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:120:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/validations.rb:37:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:21:in `save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:286:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:301:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
  devise (3.5.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  request_store (1.2.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:8:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/akhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/akhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/akhil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have tried everything everything I could for the past two days but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regions other then US East and West

The production.rb file should contain

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_host_name: 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com',
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET'],
    s3_region: ENV['S3_REGION'],
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```